# Capitalize UTF-8 text

Tags: utf-8, ocaml

I need to capitalize some text (i.e. to put the first letter in uppercase) in OCaml. Unfortunately my text is in UTF-8 and the standard library only support ASCII.

I have found an `uppercase` function in Batteries but it seems to be available only in old versions. And Camomile (which looks like the best option for processing UTF-8) seems to be dead and has very little documentation.

Comment: Camomile is what I have always imagined using. Based on some quick checking just now, it seems to be a reasonably lively project (downloaded from OPAM 776 times in the last month), modified within the last several months. But it seems very hard to access the documentation. After following a few links I ended up looking at the HTML source code for the documentation on Github. Still, there is documentation and camomile is probably what I'd look at using personally.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that how to capitalize varies depending on locale. e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Camomile is the solution here. Documentation is on sourceforge : http://camomile.sourceforge.net/dochtml/index.html
It is heavily functorized and may be intimidating at first sight, will probably take some time to master it, but it does the job.

Uppercase will be something like :

```
# open CamomileLibraryDefault;;
# module CM = Camomile.CaseMap.Make(Camomile.UTF8);;
# print_endline (CM.titlecase "привет");;
Привет
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately titlecase is not capitalize, it capitalizes every word, not just the first one.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to ygrek's help, I have found the answer to my problem:

```
let capitalize (s : string) : string =
  if s = "" then "" else
  let open CamomileLibraryDefault.Camomile in
  let module CM = CaseMap.Make(UTF8) in
  let first = UTF8.get s 0 in
  let capital = CM.uppercase (UTF8.init 1 (fun _ -> first)) in
  UTF8.init (UTF8.length s) (function 0 -> UTF8.get capital 0 | i -> UTF8.get s i)
```

Comment: For performance reasons it is better to create the module CM outside of the function